# Three.js Loading Models using Canvas Renderer

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I've created something using WebGLRenderer and now the client says that we can't use WebGL so I'm trying to convert it to Canvas. I'm trying to load a JSON model. If I create any basic geometry it looks fine but when I load a model a lot of the model isn't visible. Any recommendation as to what the issue is here?

http://plnkr.co/edit/gAZUv8eooUHNhbMVe7mo?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `CanvasRenderer` and `wireframe: true`, if you want to see the inside of the cone, you need to set

```
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

three.js r.67